# Unable to share files from drive to my application-android

Tags: android, share, drive

When i select a pdf from Google Drive and click share via 'send a copy' app crashes.

I'm trying to create a file from the intent data received.
 Uri received is content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy/enc%3DwZUW7yjtovmYjBMzKXQVChubXRmP0Qum361CVLRoUegdADMl%0A.

When i tried to create file from this uri it returns null.

Is there any way to share files from android(like image, mp3, video, pdf etc).
Create file works for dropbox, gallery etc.

```
 File file = FileHelper.getFile(this, mUri);

public static File getFile(Context context, Uri uri) {
        if (uri != null) {
            String path = getPath(context, uri);
            if (path != null && isLocal(path)) {
                return new File(path);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

 public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

        if (DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG + " File -",
                    "Authority: " + uri.getAuthority() +
                            ", Fragment: " + uri.getFragment() +
                            ", Port: " + uri.getPort() +
                            ", Query: " + uri.getQuery() +
                            ", Scheme: " + uri.getScheme() +
                            ", Host: " + uri.getHost() +
                            ", Segments: " + uri.getPathSegments().toString()
            );

        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // LocalStorageProvider
            if (isLocalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                // The path is the id
                return DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            }
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            else if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }

                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm trying to create a file from the intent data received.

Step #1: Delete all the code that you have there

Step #2: Use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`

Step #3: Create a `FileOutputStream` on a file that you can control (e.g., in `getFilesDir()` or `getCacheDir()`)

Step #4: Copy the content from the `InputStream` to the `FileOutputStream`

IOW, you treat a `Uri` much like you would a URL to a Web site, downloading the content to your own file, then using your own file.

Comment: .While downloading file how can i create file? file extension is unknown? without using extension mime type differs from original and view is differnt in my application.

Comment: @Uni: Call `getType()` on the `ContentResolver` to get the MIME type. Use `MimeTypeMap` to get a suggested file extension.

Comment: For some files extension returns null. like .json,.php files

Comment: @Uni: Sure. You will have to handle those yourself. This is not significantly different than how you use `https` URLs. Those do not need to end in a file extension, such as `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719068/unable-to-share-files-from-drive-to-my-application-android/42719129`. If you want a file extension for your downloaded copy, you will need to come up with a file extension yourself. Or, do not worry about the file extension, hold onto the MIME type, and use the MIME type for helping determine the content of your downloaded copy.